# View debugging - UITransitionViews - Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, uiviewcontroller, transition

I have some menus in my app wich are all presented modally. In my tests I noticed that the more often I switch between menus the more UITransitionViews are show in the View Debugging Window in Xcode when i capture the View Hierarchy.  Is this a normal behavior are am I missing something here. Do I need to dismiss ViewControllers somehow?
I attached a screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do, I had the same issue and the app memory usage was going up the more I switched between views (views were not dismissed).

You should use delegate where the child view controller can call so the parent view controller can dimiss children properly.